# dataTables HTML5 data-search cell attribute does not work

Tags: html, datatables

Basically i'm trying to do something like in this example

https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html

My code is below

```js
var dTable = $('#ajaxresults').DataTable({
    "order": [[1, "desc" ]],
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "ajax": "/users.json",
    createdRow: function(row, data, index) {
        if(data[6]=="Special") {
            $(row).find('td').eq(0).attr("data-search", "Special");
        }
    }
});
```

However once the dataset is loaded on page and i'm trying to search for Special nothing returns but if i view it in dev tools i can clearly see the data-search attribute being set to the column, from what i've read i think i'm adding the data-search column attribute after the initialization and that's why the search would not work ? but i've searched the entire documentation and i don't see other ways to implement this does anyone have any ideas  on this ?

P.S. i forgot to tell that the "special" word will not appear in any column just added as data-search attribute to some users, so it's not really visible but should be searchable trough the data-search attribute ..

Comment: "_...but should be searchable trough the data-search attribute_", No! As I explain in the answer it only works if your **markup** is formatted this way - you cannot inject `data-search` to `<td>`'s by code and then dataTables begin to filter according to the values in that attribute.  The example you are referring is based on preformatted markup too, and the docs in the links I gave states the difference.  If you are using AJAX, or a JSON source, you must use `column.render` (or preprocess a <table> structure in code) before initialising the dataTable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The HTML5 `data-*` attributes works *if* all cells in a column have the `data-*` attribute at the time the table is initialised. You inject `data-search` *after* each row and all its cells is inserted - thats why `data-search` doesnt work in this case.

You could use a render method instead.

```js
columnDefs : [
  { targets: [0], 
    render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
       if (type === 'filter') {
          return full[6] == "Special" ? "Special" : data
       } else {
          return data
       }
    }
  }
]
```

This will do the same, returning "Special" for col#0 when the user is typing in the searchbox, and if col#6 == "Special".

- **https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data**
- **https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render**

Comment: Thanks David! i've tried your solution before too, in  fact i've tried tons of solutions i found on the web but i could not find a good solution :( that's why i post here ... but this is not good because i don't want to modify the value in the cell the value of the cell must remain the same and the "special" word to be added to the data-search attribute so i can look for both in my search (cell value or "special" word)

Comment: P.S. i forgot to tell that the "special" word will not appear in any column just added as data-search attribute to some users, so it's not really visible but should be searchable trough the data-search attribute ..

Comment: @ClaudiuD., you are **not** modifying the value of the cell by doing as above - what happens is that a _different_ value than the cell value is returned, when and **only** when dataTables is about to filter data, i.e typically then the user types in the search box.  The **exact** same thing as `data-search` ...

Comment: Thank you for your patience David! your solution worked fine :) but i looked back in my code to see why my columnDefs and render did not worked and i was trying to alter the TD with jquery again trying to inject the data-search ... how stupid :)

Comment: +1 Thanks I didn't realise it was required in ALL cells. I was ONLY putting data-search in on cells with hyphens in their content, having a hyphen stripped version in the data-search. Once changing to all regardless of hyphens, it worked. 
Thanks for this!